# How to read a String more than 1 character at a time

Tags: java, database, string, arraylist

I am trying to make a database of sorts but with Java. I am using Arraylists to store raw customer data as they are dynamic. However, I am currently using multiple arraylists to store each variable (ID, Name, Age). My question is, would it be possible to store more than one variable separated with underscores as a customer e.g. String Customer = "A12_Charlie_32"? I would imagine that it would have something to do with Stringreader or this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < string1.length(); index++) {
    char aChar = string1.charAt(index);
}
```

If anybody has any ideas, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `String.substring`? `String.split`? Not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: I think what you want is `Customer` objects with various properties. You can then store them in a `Set` - just remember to correctly override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Could you give more information on what database you will use.

Comment: I will try all of these suggestions to see which works best. And I think that String.split was what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by what database? if you mean the fields, then they are ID, Name, DOB, Address. Sorry I'm no expert on SQL and databases

Comment: as Mena said: you can save yourself all that string splitting (and later troubles) if you create an own Customer Object in which you store your ID, name... as properties) - if every customer has a unique id - you may want to think about using a map - using the id as key (but I have no idea what you want to do with your "database" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using Arraylists to store raw customer data as they are dynamic. However, I am currently using multiple arraylists to store each variable (ID, Name, Age).

Do I understand you correctly that you store them in a structure similar to

```
List<List<String>>
```

You'd be better off creating a `Customer` class with all 3 typed properties and accessing them directly instead of parsing the String every time.
E.g.

```
public class Customer {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  // ...getters, constructor
}
```

And use it in a list

```
List<Customer>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was probably making life hard for myself by doing what I was. I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a database, the best idea is always to use a DBMS.

If you are trying to make a DBMS while not even being aware that such a thing should ***NEVER*** be called a "database", the best idea is to try something simpler.

Which of the two applies is hard to make out purely from the question as asked.

(Oh and string concatenation techniques that rely on "separator characters" will always break as soon as the chosen separator character can validly appear anywhere in the values that are concatenated together.  Not advisable.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use arraylist to store customer details then it is good if you create a class Customer(POJO Class) where you will provide all the customer related fields along with their setters/getters.
Then you can pass the object of this customer class to arraylist.
This will have 2 basic benefits :
1. You wont need to use String's split or substring function which could be costly if string is not constructed properly. It will also increase performance because what you are doing is not advisable. 
2. You can retrieve all the data related to particular customer easily.

I hope this helps.